# Rails - creating a system for drag-and-drop download

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, download

This is a problem I'm trying to think about how to approach -- I haven't actually started it yet.

What I want to do is create a system where there is a gallery of images. These images can be dropped into a folder or some icon in one part of the screen. Then, the images that have been placed in this folder should be able to be downloaded as a zip.

I was intending to use jQuery to do the drag and drop, probably with some AJAX to accomplish the rest of the stuff, but I'm really just not sure how I would accomplish doing this, or if it's even possible (like if the web application can compress the folder of images).

Also, I'd be programming in Rails 3.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a neat interface. I think jQuery drag and drop is the way to go. Once an image is dropped, trigger an AJAX request GET '/photos/download/#{photo_id}'. This action could then utilize Rails send_file, http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file.

```
def download
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  send_file @photo.image
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. Do you know how to configure send_file for multiple files?

Comment: You could use [rubyzip](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/) to make a zip  of the multiple images, and then send_file to stream the zip.